# Why does my WCF Web Service have Two Different SOAP Bindings?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I am creating the web service in c#.I have written two simple methods.when I publish my web service it will generate two binding in WSDL file.

1st

> binding name="MyWebServiceSoap" type="tns:MyWebServiceSoap"
>   2nd
>
> binding name="MyWebServiceSoap12" type="tns:MyWebServiceSoap"

The rest content is same

Comment: One is a SOAP 1.1 binding, one is a SOAP 1.2 binding.

Answer (score 0):

One is a SOAP 1.1 binding, one is a SOAP 1.2 binding.

Comment: Is it default behaviour in .net 2010 and can we control the version?

Comment: Sure. Delete one binding.

Comment: But how ? aps.net generate this wsdl automatically?

Comment: Delete one binding from the config file. And why do you _want_ to remove one binding? Does it matter?

Comment: Actualy it doesn't matter but I want to know why it is happening and how to control it?

Comment: It's a good thing. There are two versions of SOAP. This supports them both.